# What is the correct aggregate root?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, ddd-repositories

I have the following data structure:

```
class Post
{
    public string Title { get; set;}
    public Category Category { get; set;}
}
```

Bearing in mind a post **always** belongs to one and only one category is my reasoning correct?

- `Category` is the aggregate root *(since a post cannot exist without it)*
- There should be a `CategoryRepository` (with methods such as `GetCategory` and `GetPost`) but not a `PostRepository` (because `Post` is not an aggregate root)

Comment: I didn't get the point that you're not considering to have `PostRepository`. Probably having `GetPost` is quite logical to fit in `CategoryRepository` but `Post` have it's own domain where it has it's sole purpose. Please let me know if I have missed anything

Comment: @MunimAbdul Since `Post` is not an aggregate root and repositories should only be created for aggregate roots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How do you want to reference instances of `Post`? Is `Post.Title` a unique identifier for a `Post`? If so, then `Post` *is* a valid aggregate root and you should create a `PostRepository` which retrieves an instance of `Post` given it's `Title`.

Take the example of a car. A car must have a colour, but stating that the colour is the aggregate root just because a car cannot exist without one is the wrong thing to do. I want to reference a car independently given it's license plate number (which is independent of it's colour). The fact that it must have a colour is simply a feature of my car domain model which states that I cannot construct a car instance without supplying the colour.

Comment: Another good example - tags. You do not create tag "programming" before you write post about programming, you associate it.

Answer (score 1):

I often cite this resource when it comes to aggregate root design considerations
 [RavenDB - StackOverflow style voting with Live Projections](http://codeofrob.com/archive/2010/12/16/ravendb-stackoverflow-style-voting-with-live-projections.aspx). This addresses some of your key thought process and should show you why Category would be a VERY POOR aggregate root.